# responsive site don't load correctly on mobile device but on desktop with small width yes

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I've got a problem , that wordpress [page](http://berlinstartup.events/events)
don't load correctly on mobile devices but on desktop with smaller width loads fine.
I've got meta tag with `width=device-width` and `inicial-scale =1`.
On my phone with 320px width site loads as about 800px but when I check it on desktop browser with 320px it looks how it should.
Where can be a problem ?

Comment: Please post your media queries from CSS or any JavaScript you're using to resize the content.

Comment: have you set the `viewport` meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons..!

1) You might have used a many CSS (-webkit-,-moz-,-o-,-ms-) animations,whose properties are supported only by your browser.

2) Check latest android/mobile device, (which is designed to support all type of CSS behaviours).

3) Check your media queries, If you are using Chrome, you might have used only webkit.
You better use all the properties to support all kind of browsers,(-webkit-,-moz-,-ms-,-o-).

4) Use more JavaScripts than CSS.

5) Try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/566378/browser-plugin-to-resize-window-for-brower-testing) for debugging if you haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your page IS loading at the proper width. After it loads, some code executes and resizes the window. I noticed the following in your JS code:

```
        if ( tribe_ev.data.v_width <= tribe_ev.data.mobile_break ) {
            $body.addClass( 'tribe-mobile' );
        }
        else {
            $body.removeClass( 'tribe-mobile' );
        }
```

I set some breakpoints to test it, and this is where the resizing is done.

(**I edited my answer and removed code that had nothing to do with it**)

Comment: i commented this line in 2 JS files but i didn't helped . You wrote you changed the breakpoints but help that in mobile ? 
In addition I search for this class in css files but only thing i found was it set padding-top to 0 .

Answer (score 0):

problem solved .
in Js file was line whenever device has Android iOS ect. make body width 1024px .